# Actualizar ubicación de otros usuarios android

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps

Tengo una actividad de usuario y se muestran los 3 conductores, pero cuando un conductor se mueve en el mapa de usuario no se actualiza la posición del conductor.
Hay alguna forma de que cuando los conductores cambien de posición el usuario pueda vea ese cambio sin necesidad de volver a abrir esa actividad?
Estoy intentado poner la llamada de mis datos en LocationCallback pero cuando se ingresa por primera vez si se ve la ubicación de los conductores.

```
 LocationCallback mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
        for(Location location: locationResult.getLocations()) {
            if (getApplicationContext() != null) {

                mCurrentLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

                // OBTENER LA LOCALIZACION DEL USUARIO EN TIEMPO REAL
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(
                        new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))
                                .zoom(15f)
                                .build()
                ));



            }
            String empresaID=getIntent().getStringExtra("idEmpresa");
            //final String idEmpresa = SharedPreferencesManager.getSomeStringValue(AppConst.PREF_IDEMPRESA);

            SolicitudEmpresa solicitudEmpresa=new SolicitudEmpresa(empresaID);

            Call<RespuestaEmpresas> call = smartCityService.getDrivers(solicitudEmpresa);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<RespuestaEmpresas>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<RespuestaEmpresas> call, @NotNull Response<RespuestaEmpresas> response) {

                    Double lat1 = Double.valueOf(response.body().getLat1());
                    Double long1 = Double.valueOf(response.body().getLong1());
                    Double lat2 = Double.valueOf(response.body().getLat2());
                    Double long2 = Double.valueOf(response.body().getLong2());
                    Double lat3 = Double.valueOf(response.body().getLat3());
                    Double long3 = Double.valueOf(response.body().getLong3());

                    if(response.isSuccessful()){

                        LatLng c1 = new LatLng(lat1, long1);
                        LatLng c2 = new LatLng(lat2, long2);
                        LatLng c3 = new LatLng(lat3, long3);

                        if(c1!=null){
                            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(c1).title("Conductor disponible").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bus_logo)));
                        }
                        if(c2!=null){
                            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(c2).title("Conductor disponible").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bus_logo)));
                        }
                        if(c3!=null){
                            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(c3).title("Conductor disponible").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bus_logo)));
                        }


                    }else{

                        Toast.makeText(MapsUserActivity.this, "no hay datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<RespuestaEmpresas> call, Throwable t) {


                    Toast.makeText(MapsUserActivity.this, "algo paso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: "pero cuando se ingresa por primera vez si se ve la ubicación de los conductores.", entonces cual sería el problema? deseas que no se vea la úbicación la primera vez?

Comment: lo que deseo es que  cuando se mueva el conductor, en el mapa del usuario se vea también el cambio.

Comment: Si quieres que se actualice la pantalla en la que te encuentras, puedes refrescar datos cada cierto tiempo, por ej. 10segundos (polling), es fácil de mantener.  Para hacer el polling puedes usar un handler con un delay y el runnable ejecutar el método.